# Cmake Error: variables NOTFOUND when configuring or building openpose on windows 10

Tags: c++, cmake, openpose

Environment: windows 10 x64, visual studio 2017 community(has installed c++ modules following the video), cuda 10.2.89, cudnn 7.6.5, cmake 3.16-rc3, openpose-1.5.0.

Following the official README document and [recommended video](https://youtu.be/QC9GTb6Wsb4), I try to build openpose with python api.

Unfortunately, when I try to use the Cmake(Version 3.16) configure or build the source code of openpose-1.5.0, I meet
a problem.

There are some variables below set to NOTFOUND in cmake, and I can't solve it.

I checked the "WITH_PYTHON" option, so there is some information about "BOOST". If I don't check it, it will disappear.

I have tried to install the boost-1.66.0 and add it to path, but it doesn't work.

The error information is here:

```
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
BOOST_FILESYSTEM_LIB_RELEASE
    linked by target "openpose" in directory C:/code/source_code/openpose-1.5.0/src/openpose
    linked by target "Calibration" in directory C:/code/source_code/openpose-1.5.0/examples/calibration
    linked by target "OpenPoseDemo" in directory C:/code/source_code/openpose-1.5.0/examples/openpose
    linked by target "pyopenpose" in directory C:/code/source_code/openpose-1.5.0/python/openpose
    ...
BOOST_SYSTEM_LIB_RELEASE
    linked by target "openpose" in directory C:/code/source_code/openpose-1.5.0/src/openpose
    linked by target "Calibration" in directory C:/code/source_code/openpose-1.5.0/examples/calibration
    linked by target "OpenPoseDemo" in directory C:/code/source_code/openpose-1.5.0/examples/openpose
    linked by target "pyopenpose" in directory C:/code/source_code/openpose-1.5.0/python/openpose
    ...
Caffe_LIB
    linked by target "openpose" in directory C:/code/source_code/openpose-1.5.0/src/openpose
    linked by target "Calibration" in directory C:/code/source_code/openpose-1.5.0/examples/calibration
    linked by target "OpenPoseDemo" in directory C:/code/source_code/openpose-1.5.0/examples/openpose
    linked by target "pyopenpose" in directory C:/code/source_code/openpose-1.5.0/python/openpose
    ...
Caffe_Proto_LIB
    linked by target "openpose" in directory C:/code/source_code/openpose-1.5.0/src/openpose
    linked by target "Calibration" in directory C:/code/source_code/openpose-1.5.0/examples/calibration
    linked by target "OpenPoseDemo" in directory C:/code/source_code/openpose-1.5.0/examples/openpose
    linked by target "pyopenpose" in directory C:/code/source_code/openpose-1.5.0/python/openpose
    ...
GFLAGS_LIBRARY_DEBUG
    linked by target "openpose" in directory C:/code/source_code/openpose-1.5.0/src/openpose
    linked by target "Calibration" in directory C:/code/source_code/openpose-1.5.0/examples/calibration
    linked by target "OpenPoseDemo" in directory C:/code/source_code/openpose-1.5.0/examples/openpose
    linked by target "pyopenpose" in directory C:/code/source_code/openpose-1.5.0/python/openpose
    ...
GFLAGS_LIBRARY_RELEASE
    linked by target "openpose" in directory C:/code/source_code/openpose-1.5.0/src/openpose
    linked by target "Calibration" in directory C:/code/source_code/openpose-1.5.0/examples/calibration
    linked by target "OpenPoseDemo" in directory C:/code/source_code/openpose-1.5.0/examples/openpose
    linked by target "pyopenpose" in directory C:/code/source_code/openpose-1.5.0/python/openpose
    ...
GLOG_LIBRARY_DEBUG
    linked by target "openpose" in directory C:/code/source_code/openpose-1.5.0/src/openpose
    linked by target "Calibration" in directory C:/code/source_code/openpose-1.5.0/examples/calibration
    linked by target "OpenPoseDemo" in directory C:/code/source_code/openpose-1.5.0/examples/openpose
    linked by target "pyopenpose" in directory C:/code/source_code/openpose-1.5.0/python/openpose
    ...
GLOG_LIBRARY_RELEASE
    linked by target "openpose" in directory C:/code/source_code/openpose-1.5.0/src/openpose
    linked by target "Calibration" in directory C:/code/source_code/openpose-1.5.0/examples/calibration
    linked by target "OpenPoseDemo" in directory C:/code/source_code/openpose-1.5.0/examples/openpose
    linked by target "pyopenpose" in directory C:/code/source_code/openpose-1.5.0/python/openpose
    ...
OpenCV_LIBS
    linked by target "openpose" in directory C:/code/source_code/openpose-1.5.0/src/openpose
    linked by target "Calibration" in directory C:/code/source_code/openpose-1.5.0/examples/calibration
    linked by target "OpenPoseDemo" in directory C:/code/source_code/openpose-1.5.0/examples/openpose
    linked by target "pyopenpose" in directory C:/code/source_code/openpose-1.5.0/python/openpose
    ...
```

Because the text is too long, I use replace some repeated information with ... .

Thanks for everyone's answer!

Answer (score 0):

In the "3rdparty" folder, put archives of caffe, caffe3rd and opencv(**be care of version!**). Then unzip them
to the appropriate folder.
(This is the work of "getxxx.bat", but it will delete the archives after running it, causing camke to re-download it when configure. Please don't delete the archives)

Please refer to the code of "getxxx.bat" for the name of the unzipped folder.

Otherwise, it prompts for some variables set to NOTFOUND.